# Push git branches to separate servers

Tags: git

On my local machine I have two branches - master, develop.
Master branch is set up to deploy to a server via a hook and works as expected. With the develop branch, I'm trying to set up a hook on a separate server and push to that. So as I work, I can switch branches and push as needed.

I've set up my remote repo with a `git init --bare` and applied the correlating hook.

After setting the remote for the second server and pushing, I get this error:

```
remote: fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born
```

As I understand it, I need to create the develop branch on the remote server.

For pushing:

```
git push origin master
git push dev develop
```

I've tried `git push -u dev develop` but still no luck.

If there's a better way, I'm open. I understand that this might not be the best way to go about doing so and would appreciate any insight.

Here's the hook I'm using.

`git --work-tree=/home/20258/users/.home/domains/beta.certainstrings.com/html/ --git-dir=/home/20258/users/.home/domains/beta.certainstrings.com/html/repo/site.git checkout -f`

It's the same hook as the other server on dev.certainstrings.com, where it's working, and I've ran `chmod +x post-receive` as well.

Comment: The `remote:` in front of the error message means it's coming from the other system (the server).  No doubt there is some error in the hook you have set up over there, but without being able to see the hook, there's no way to tell what the error is.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm having the same issue and it seems like I'm just overlooking something simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one remote server, with a hook trying to switch to an unborn branch, then pushing said branch is a good idea.

But you should push both branches to the same `dev` server:

```
git checkout master
git push -u dev master 
git checkout develop
git push -u dev develop
```

That way, if your hook depends on any of those branches, they are both there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm actually trying to push to separate servers.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can...  example

```
git remote add server2 git@github.com:foo/project.git
git push server2 master
```

this will setup the new server as server2 and you can then push any branch to it..  please let me know if this is not what you are looking for